# "react-admin" proxy issue with dataProvider

Tags: proxy, dataprovider, react-admin

I have my build running on my localhost. I have the dataProvider working properly with all standard views using https (i.e. "Show", Create"). I want to create data from within a function like this:

```
import { CREATE, GET_ONE, UPDATE } from 'react-admin';
import dataProviderFactory from '../dataProvider';

dataProviderFactory(
  process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_HTTPS_URL
).then(dataProvider => {
  dataProvider(CREATE, 'batches', {
    data: {
      name: "test"
    }
  })
  .then(response => response.data)
  .then(data => {
    console.log('data', data);
  });
});
```

The exact same POST in the entity 'batches' works from the standard react-admin "create" template, but with this function, it fails. It appears to be trying to proxy to 'localhost' instead of maintaining the root API URL. Is there some other way I need to either pull the dataProvider from the Admin controller, or can I spec the proxy root url for the dataProvider?

dataProvier.js:

```
export default type => {
    return import('./rest').then(provider => provider.default);
};
```

rest.js:

```
import simpleRestProvider from 'ra-data-simple-rest';
import Constants from "../constants/Constants";
import { fetchUtils } from 'react-admin';
import SimpleRestClient from '../utils/SimpleRestClient';
import AppConfig from '../AppConfig';

const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
  if (!options.headers) {
    options.headers = new Headers();
  }
  if(!url.endsWith("/authenticate") && localStorage.getItem('token') !== null) {
    options.user = {
      authenticated: true,
      token: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
    }
  }
  return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
}

// Use custom rest client. For fakeserver use react admin rest client
const restDataProvider = !AppConfig.useFakeServer ? SimpleRestClient(Constants.urls.apiBaseUrl, httpClient) :
  simpleRestProvider(Constants.urls.apiBaseUrl, httpClient);

export default (type, resource, params) =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
      if (!AppConfig.useFakeServer) {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(restDataProvider(type, resource, params)), 500);
      } else {
        resolve(restDataProvider(type, resource, params));
      }
    }
  );
```

Comment: Can you share the code of the `dataProviderFactory` ?

Comment: @Gildas - added in dataProviderFactory code.

Comment: in your dataProviderFactory, I fail to see where you are using the `type` parameter